# ng-repeat display range

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to display ranges like 3 4 5 6 or 6 7 8 9

How can I do this?

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="num in nums">{{num}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/duketopmost/n9brs8hh/

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `limitTo`? 
docs (angularjs v1.3.15) : https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/filter/limitTo

```
<li ng-repeat="num in nums | limitTo: 6 | limitTo: -4">{{num}}</li>
```

num = 3, 4, 5, 6

```
<li ng-repeat="num in nums | limitTo: 9 | limitTo: -4">{{num}}</li>
```

num = 6, 7, 8, 9

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n9brs8hh/1/

---

EDIT: another option would be to create a `.filter` for more complex operations perhaps.

Comment: Excelent, and I don't know use of negative numbers. But I think limitTo chaining other limitTo has a complex logic. Maybe, the best is a specific filter, like a paginate filter.